# How does ls --tab-size work?

Tags: ls

I can't figure out what does `ls --tab-size=COLS` (or `ls -T<COLS>`) do.

From man:

> assume tab stops at each COLS instead of 8

And, for instance, what's going on here? Or what would be a useful example?

```
$ touch a b c d
$ ls --color=never
a  b  c  d
$ ls --color=never -T0
a  b  c  d
$ ls --color=never -T1
a    b   c   d
$ ls --color=never -T2
a  b    c  d
$ ls --color=never -T3
a   b   c   d
$ ls --color=never -T4
a  b  c  d
$ ls --color=never -T5
a  b  c  d
$ ls --color=never -T6
a  b    c  d
```

Comment: It won't use tabs if you're printing with color (gotta read the source code, since the info page is lacking).

Comment: @ThomasDickey added proper flag, no changes.

Comment: I don't totally understand it, but I think the misunderstanding is something to do with `ls` printing tab _characters_. [This](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2008-05/msg00151.html) [thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2008-05/msg00154.html) has more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--tabsize=cols` / `-T` option is there to adjust the tab size of `ls` to the tab size of your terminal or to disable the use of tabs. This makes sense if your terminal is using a "non-standard" value != 8 and the output is garbled.

The description of `info ls` is slightly better:

> Assume that each tab stop is COLS columns wide. The default is 8.
>   `ls` uses tabs where possible in the output, for efficiency. If COLS is zero, do not use tabs at all.
>
> Some terminal emulators might not properly align columns to the right of a TAB following a non-ASCII byte.  You can avoid that issue by using the `-T0` option or put `TABSIZE=0` in your  environment, to tell `ls` to align using spaces, not tabs.

Example:

```
$ ls
adipiscing  consectetur  elit  felis      in      lorem   nulla     posuere  tincidunt
amet        dolor        et    fermentum  ipsum   mauris  nunc      sit      venenatis
arcu        donec        ex    id         libero  nec     pharetra  tempor   vulputate
```

This looks good, also with `-T0` and `-T8` and

```
$ echo -e "a\tb"
a       b
```

reveals my tab width is set to 8 characters.

But

```
$ ls -T3
adipiscing      consectetur  elit  felis                in                lorem  nulla    posuere  tincidunt
amet                    dolor                    et      fermentum      ipsum   mauris  nunc              sit            venenatis
arcu                    donec                    ex      id                     libero  nec              pharetra  tempor   vulputate
```

looks pretty bad.

Now set the tab-stops to 3 characters and try again:

```
$ tabs -3; echo -e "a\tb"; ls -T3
a  b
adipiscing  consectetur  elit  felis      in      lorem   nulla     posuere  tincidunt
amet        dolor        et    fermentum  ipsum   mauris  nunc      sit      venenatis
arcu        donec        ex    id         libero  nec     pharetra  tempor   vulputate
```

And the output is nicely formatted again.